# Enclosing a router-link tag in a button in vuejs

Tags: button, vue.js, vue-router

Can I wrap or enclose a `router-link` tag in a `button` tag?

When I press the button, I want it to route me to the desired page.

Comment: For answers in 2019 and Vue Router 3.1.0+, scroll down for up-to-date answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/58495529/90674

Answer (score 171, accepted):

You can use [`tag` prop](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html).

```
<router-link to="/foo" tag="button">foo</router-link>
```

Please [use v-slot](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#removal-of-event-and-tag-props-in-router-link) if you use 3.0+ (thanks to [Romain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45638239/enclosing-a-router-link-tag-in-a-button-in-vuejs/58495529#comment126561908_45638390) and [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58495529/6279569))

Comment: What if that button accepts some props? How to pass them out?

Comment: @andcl I had the same question, I posted the answer below, which was told to me by the Vue-Router team on GitHub here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/3003

Comment: i tried to upvote this almost a year after i already did! akkk thanks again

Comment: But "tag" is no longer supported by vue-router. See [official migration note](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#removal-of-event-and-tag-props-in-router-link). And anyway, I don't recall exactly, but I doubt it handled additional link features and accessibility.

Answer (score 113):

While the answers on here are all good, none seem to be the simplest solution. After some quick research, it seems that the real easiest way to make a button use vue-router is with the `router.push` call. This can be used within a .vue template like this:

```
<button @click="$router.push('about')">Click to Navigate</button>
```

Super simple and clean. I hope someone else finds this useful!

Source: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html

Comment: Yes thank you!  This was the simplest, and worked perfectly.  And I could style my button however I chose.

If you need to use params, you can also do something like this:

<button @click="$router.push({name: 'about', params: { id: $route.params.id },})">Click to Navigate</button>

Comment: The best answer for me

Comment: Note that this answer this won't allow to use browser supported features such as press Ctrl+Click to open link in new tab or preview of link in bottom-left corner of browser window.

Comment: This broke accessibility

Answer (score 57):

**@choasia**'s answer is correct.

Alternatively, you could wrap a `button` tag in a `router-link` tag like so:

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'myRoute'}">
  <button id="myButton" class="foo bar">Go!</button>
</router-link>
```

This is not so clean because your button will be inside a link element (`<a>`). However, the advantage is that you have a full control on your button, which may be necessary if you work with a front-end framework like Bootstrap.

I have never used this technique on buttons, to be honest. But I did this on divs quite often...

Comment: Additionally one can specify tag="span" inside <router-link> so it doesn't apply <a> styles which gives even better control on the looks:   <router-link to="/foo" tag="span">
   <Button>
    Button Text
   </Button>
  </router-link>

Comment: But the words in button (e.g. "Go!" in your example) will have the blue underline, which is not beautiful...

Comment: Even with frameworks like Bootstrap, this is hardly ever necessary, because you can include standard attributes like class right in the router-link tag, and these will be applied to the rendered element, even a button, when you use tag="button":
<router-link tag="button" class="btn btn-primary" to="..."></router-link>

Answer (score 21):

### Official Answer as of 2023

Use the slots api [Documentation Here](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#v-slot-api-3-1-0)

#### Example using the slots api

```html
<router-link
  to="/about"
  v-slot="{href, route, navigate}"
  >
    <button :href="href" @click="navigate" class='whatever-you-want'>
      {{ route.name }}
    </button>
</router-link>
```

If you think this is unintuitive/verbose, please complain [over here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/3003)

#### Why are the other answers problematic?

- @choasia's answer (using the tag prop) is deprecated and doesn't allow for props to be passed to the component
- @Badacadabra's answer causes problems with CSS especially if the button is from a library (ex: adding a margin, or positioning)

Comment: If you're not on version >= 3.1.0, the item in the slot will silently be ignored without any errors show. Link to docs: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#v-slot-api-3-1-0

Comment: i cannot download 3.1.0 it says the latest is 3.0.0 rc

Comment: It's not Vue 3.1.0, it's vue-router 3.1.0.

Comment: Thanks @Anuga, fixed it 
And thanks @ sshow, documentation is linked now.

Comment: Use the modern slot API `<template #default="{href,route,navigate}">`

Comment: @Steven could you link the documentation on that? I haven't seen it yet but that looks interesting

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-slots.html#named-slots-shorthand

Comment: Hmm I'm not totally sure how that would apply to the example. Are you saying to replace `v-slot="{href, route, navigate}"` with `#default="{href, route, navigate}"`? It looks like v-slots is shorter, still valid, and backwards compatible with Vue 2

Comment: The ```:href``` should not be bound on the button. The targeted url is already held by the property ```to="xxx"``` of the ```<router-link>```

Comment: Maybe it has changed but screen readers, browser extensions, and other behavior like ctrl/cmd + click (to open link in a new background tab) wouldn't work unless the href property was set directly. Screen-readers and extensions they can't easily see inside of onClick behavior, which is why its important to set the href for usability

Comment: Where is it written in the question that there's the requirement to pass props?

Answer (score 14):

Thanks to Wes Winder's answer, and extending it to include route params:

```
<button @click="$router.push({name: 'about-something', params: { id: 'abc123' },})">Click to Navigate</button>
```

And reiterating the source which Wes provided: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html

Answer (score 8):

Now days (VueJS >= 2.x) you would do:

```
<router-link tag="button" class="myClass" id="button" :to="place.to.go">Go!</router-link>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Routing methods using method as well routing
>    1. Router link
>
> `<router-link to="/login">Login </router-link>`

2. When click on button that type call another route.

> ```
> <template>
>     <input type="submit" value="Login" @click="onLogIn" class="btn float-right btn-primary">
>     </template>
> ```

```
<script>
export default {
    name:'auth',
    data() {
        return {}
    },
    methods: {
        onLogIn() {
            this.$router.replace('/dashboard');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on Vue CLI 2 and this one has worked for me!

```
<router-link to="/about-creator">
<button>About Creator</button>
</router-link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly no, there is currently no way to do this *properly*.

I say *properly* because there obviously are several solutions that were already proposed to this question.
The problem is: they **seem to work** but really they **are not correct**.

Here is why:

1. It is invalid to put any actionable element inside of another in html (there's plenty of invalid html out there and it has not caught fire yet, am I right?).
2. Most of the solutions I've seen here don't provide any navigation accessibility (nor link features such as "open link in new tab").
3. The one that does (by Jeff Hykin) has a couple of draw backs too:

   - It fails to observe point 1)
   - In his snippet, `@click="navigate"` is not necessary because `<router-link>` is really an `<a>`, which will trigger a navigation by itself and `href` is totally useless to a `<button>`.
   - EDIT: Answer by Badacadabra is a bit better, but still point 1)

---

Assuming what you want is to **reuse a properly styled button component to be used as a valid accessible link**.

The real solution and you won't like it (I don't), is to create a component for the button, create another for the link and put whatever can be reused in yet another file (a base actionable component for example).

If the button comes from a library, well, another example that libraries never really solve every problem for you.

Answer (score -1):

An example using bootstrap-vue and creating a link with the id inside a table row:

```
<b-table :fields="fields" :items="items">
    <template v-slot:cell(action)="data">
        <router-link :to="`/rounds/${data.item.id}`" v-slot="{ href, route, navigate}">
            <b-button :href="href" @click="navigate" color="primary" style="text">{{ data.item.id }}</b-button>
        </router-link>
    </template>
</b-table>
```

Where `fields` and `items` are the columns names and the table content, respectively.

Answer (score -1):

```
    // literal string path
router.push('home')

// object
router.push({ path: 'home' })

// named route
router.push({ name: 'user', params: { userId: '123' } })

// with query, resulting in /register?plan=private
router.push({ path: 'register', query: { plan: 'private' } })
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the v-btn component you can simply:

```
<v-btn onclick="location.href='https://www.Google.com'" type="button" class="mb-4">Google</v-btn>
```