# following links in vue with button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Cheers everyone. I have encountered a problem with following links.

I need to assign link to a button. Can I wrap router-link in a button?

```
<template lang="html">
    <button @click="" v-if="status == 'SUCCESS'"><font-awesome-icon icon="check" /></button>
    <button @click="" v-else-if="status == 'CRASH'"><font-awesome-icon icon="times" /></button>
    <button @click="" v-else-if="status == 'NO_DATA'"><font-awesome-icon icon="minus" /></button>
    <button v-else>What?</button>
</template>
```

Comment: while this is possible, could you clarify why you cannot make the button an anchor? That solution would be much simpler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enclosing a router-link tag in a button in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45638239/enclosing-a-router-link-tag-in-a-button-in-vuejs)

Comment: @Daniel anchor? How is that possible in vue?

Comment: @Stepykun are you using vue-router?

Comment: can you show use of the `vue-router`? It's hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

Just assign the `:to=""` value to your button and it'll be turned into a valid `vue-router` link.

For example:

```
<button :to="{name: 'Home'}" />
```

Would be turned into:

```
<a href="/index"></a>
```